# touch event outside my subview should cause the subview to disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have a UIView subclass which is displayed once i click navigation bar button. I'm trying to imitate a UIPopover kind of view in iphone.
The thing i'm stuck with is that i have to remove the subview when touched outside the box.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an invisible layer over all the layers to check for the touches whenever your subview appears, and you can manually check if the coordinate is in the subview then just manually remove it from your main view.

You can see an example here to dismiss the keyboard instead of removing a view:

http://www.ke-cai.net/2011/05/tap-background-to-dismiss-keyboard-for.html

Answer (score 3):

When you define your popup view you have to define it's visible rect (frame).
In your main view controller, when the user tap the screen, retrieve the touch location and check that the point is not contained into your popup frame.

This is just an example to illustrate this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if (aTouch.tapCount == 1)
    {
        CGPoint p = [aTouch locationInView:self.view];
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(yourpopupview.frame, p))
        {
            // dismiss the popup
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it'll help you.